# Given the vectors a and b orthogonal to each other find the vector V in terms of a and b where V.a=0 ,V.b=1 and [V a b]=1 ??

Tags: vectors

Given the vectors a and b orthogonal to each other find the  vector V in terms of a and b where V.a=0 ,V.b=1 and [V a b]=1 ?? I am not getting any way to solve this cud u pls help me with this and pls give proper and full explanation.

Comment: What is $[V \, a \, b]$?

Comment: If your $[V \, a \, b]$ is for the determinant with $V, a$ and $b$ as the column vectors. Then $V$ cannot lie in the plane of $a$ and $b$. That means you cannot simply express $V$ as a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. You need a third component $a \times b$.

Comment: @Anurag A I think it means the scalar triple product.

Comment: That's going to be tough if $b$ is the zero vector (which is consistent with the problem statement).

Comment: @John Hughes If either of $a$ or $b$ is zero vector then it will not satisfy all the requirements of the problem (assuming Rohan's interpretation of OP's symbol). Because $[V \, a \, b]$ will denote the volume of the parallelopiped with $V, a$ and $b$ as the edges.

Comment: The *requirements* are that $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal.In my book, that doesn't entail either being nonzero. (Your definition may vary, of course). Roughly speaking: I'm criticizing the sloppy formulation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope I understood properly.

---

We have $\vec a. \vec v =0$. Also $\vec a\times \vec b$ is perpendicular to both $\vec a, \vec b$ and $\vec a\times \vec b$ are mutually perpendicular vectors. We also know that $[\vec a\vec a\vec b] = [\vec b \vec a\vec b] = 0$.

Therefore $$\vec v = p\vec a+q\vec b+r(\vec a\times \vec b)...(1)$$ Now, as $\vec v. \vec a=0 \Rightarrow p=0$. Also, $\vec v.\vec b=1\Rightarrow 0+q|b^2|+0=1 \Rightarrow q=\frac{1}{|b^2|}$.

We have $\vec v.(\vec a\times \vec b) = p.0 + q.0 + r|\vec a\times \vec b|^2 =1 \Rightarrow [\vec v \vec a \vec b] = r|\vec a\times \vec b|^2 = 1\Rightarrow r= \frac{1}{|\vec a\times \vec b|^2}$.

Now substitute in $(1)$. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx a lot ,but cud pls again explain how did you get eq1 and after that??

Comment: That I understood but cud u pls give brief explanation,how did u get the values of p and q???

Comment: Yea That is fine but how with the dot product of v.a we will get value of p??

Comment: Then to find r how did u take a=0 and b=0??

Comment: I understood this but just wanted to ask if there is any other way to sove this.

Comment: So, the long explanations of mine just for this statement of yours that you know this method? Then why did you ask? Very disappointing.

Comment: I really did not wanted to disappoint you bro . After your proper explanations i got this one and thank you very  much for that but just was asking if there was any other method too.

Comment: Thank you. I feel there is no other easy method than this. Happy it helped.